# Finding Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) when x depends on \theta

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate the Maximum Likelihood Estimator when x depends on $\theta$.

For example, to find the MLE of $$f(x) =\frac{2x}{\theta^2} \mbox{ where } 0\le x \leq \theta $$ we cannot use the traditional methods of finding Maximum Likelihood Estimators. Can someone please explain to me the steps I should take to find the MLE of this function?

Comment: MLE finds the parameter $\theta$ for which your data has the largest likelihood. So you need to tell us what your data is and what your likelihood is. And what is $f(x)$?

Comment: My data is a random sample (X1, X2, ..., Xn) from X. f(x) is in the question.

Comment: Your likelihood is thus$$L(\theta|x_!,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{2^n\prod x_i\mathbb I_{(0,\theta)}(x_i)}{\theta^{2n}}$$and you have to maximise this function of $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming independent values of the observations, the likelihood would be
$$ 2^n\prod_{i=1}^nx_i/(\theta^{2n})$$
In order to maximize this, you would want $\theta$ to be as small as possible (the numerator is fixed once the sample is taken); but you are constrained by the fact that $x < \theta$, so your optimal choice would be $\hat\theta_{MLE} = \max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$.